# Why am I getting double labels?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am trying to make a swiper widget that contains a list of items but I keep getting double labels. I have really been messing around with different layouts to see if that changes as well as how I insert the swiperitems. I cant find anything online with someone having a similiar issue. I'm new to kivy so I'm sure its prob something simple

This is my python file.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import TwoLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.swiper.swiper import MDSwiperItem

class MySwiperItem(MDSwiperItem):
    pass

class DemoApp(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        return Builder.load_file('demo.kv')
    
    
    def on_start(self):

        SwiperTest = MySwiperItem()

        SwiperTest.ids.header.text = "test"
        SwiperTest.ids.list.add_widget(
            TwoLineListItem(
                text = "text1",
                secondary_text = "text2"
            )
        )

        self.root.ids.swiper.add_widget(
            SwiperTest
        )

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

and this is my kivy file.

```
<DrawerClickableItem@MDNavigationDrawerItem>
    focus_color: "#e7e4c0"
    text_color: "#4a4939"
    icon_color: "#4a4939"
    ripple_color: "#c5bdd2"
    selected_color: "#0c6c4d"


<DrawerLabelItem@MDNavigationDrawerItem>
    text_color: "#4a4939"
    icon_color: "#4a4939"
    focus_behavior: False
    selected_color: "#4a4939"
    _no_ripple_effect: True

<MySwiperItem>:
    orientation: "vertical"            
    MDLabel:
        id: header
        font_style: "H5"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1] + dp(40)
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "top": 1}
        md_bg_color: "grey"

    MDScrollView:
        MDList:
            id: list
                

MDScreen:
    MDNavigationLayout:

        MDScreenManager:

            MDScreen:
                orientation: "vertical"

                MDTopAppBar:
                    id: nav_bar
                    title: "Smart Indoor Watering System"
                    elevation: 4
                    pos_hint: {"top": 1}
                    md_bg_color: "#e7e4c0"
                    specific_text_color: "#4a4939"
                    left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

                
                MDSwiper:
                    id: swiper
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: root.height - nav_bar.height - dp(40)
                    y: root.height - self.height - nav_bar.height - dp(20)


        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            radius: (0, 16, 16, 0)

            MDNavigationDrawerMenu:

                MDNavigationDrawerHeader:
                    title: "Header title"
                    title_color: "#4a4939"
                    text: "Header text"
                    spacing: "4dp"
                    padding: "12dp", 0, 0, "56dp"

                MDNavigationDrawerLabel:
                    text: "Mail"

                DrawerClickableItem:
                    icon: "gmail"
                    right_text: "+99"
                    text_right_color: "#4a4939"
                    text: "Inbox"

                DrawerClickableItem:
                    icon: "send"
                    text: "Outbox"

                MDNavigationDrawerDivider:

                MDNavigationDrawerLabel:
                    text: "Labels"

                DrawerLabelItem:
                    icon: "information-outline"
                    text: "Label"

                DrawerLabelItem:
                    icon: "information-outline"
                    text: "Label"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `demo.kv` is being loaded twice. In addition to your explicit `Builder.load_file()`, the `kv` file is also loaded automatically by the `App`. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.load_kv). Try changing the name of the `demo.kv` to something unrelated to the `App` name.

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot, I figured it would be something simple